# Why my bind event did not invoke in Wechat little-program?

Tags: wechat

This is my code below:

`search.wxml`:

```
<view class="search">
    <view class="section">
        <input id="input-word" placeholder="请输入您要查询的文本" focus/>
        <view id="cancel-button" bindTap="navigateBack" class="navigator" >取消</view>
    </view>
</view>
```

`search.js`:

```
Page({
  onLoad: function () {
    console.log('onLoad-search')

  },

  // back
  navigateBack: function(e) {
    console.log("back");  // this do not log out, when I click my view
  }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

The position of the function "navigateBack" is wrong.You should put it like this:

> ```
> navigateBack: function(e) {
>     console.log("back");  // this do not log out, when I click my view
> }
> onload: function() {
>     console.log('onLoad-search')
> }
> ```